# How can I auto-assign a role to a new member with my bot?

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

The title suggests it. Is there any way for the bot to detect when a user joined the guild and automatically grant that user a specific role? I want to automatically grant every user the "member" role, how can I achieve this? I am not at all experienced with C#.

I have tried this, with no success:

```
 public async Task auto_role(SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        await user.AddRoleAsync((Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Member")));
    }
```

Comment: Have u granted the bot the right permissions to set roles for new members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to add a role to any newly joined guild member, you should not be touching the command system at all since, well, it's not a command!

What you *do* want to do is hook something like the [UserJoined](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_UserJoined) event, which is fired whenever a new user joins a guild.

So, for example, you may want to do something like this:

```
public class MemberAssignmentService
{
    private readonly ulong _roleId;
    public MemberAssignmentService(DiscordSocketClient client, ulong roleId)
    {
        // Hook the evnet
        client.UserJoined += AssignMemberAsync;

        // Note that we are using role identifier here instead
        // of name like your original solution; this is because
        // a role name check could easily be circumvented by a new role
        // with the exact name.
        _roleId = roleId;
    }

    private async Task AssignMemberAsync(SocketGuildUser guildUser)
    {
        var guild = guildUser.Guild;
        // Check if the desired role exist within this guild.
        // If not, we simply bail out of the handler.
        var role = guild.GetRole(_roleId);
        if (role == null) return;
        // Check if the bot user has sufficient permission
        if (!guild.CurrentUser.GuildPermissions.Has(GuildPermissions.ManageRoles)) return;

        // Finally, we call AddRoleAsync
        await guildUser.AddRoleAsync(role);
    }
}
```